# MS Access update query reversing table placement in query. Why does it work?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question on SQL execution sequence. I'm using nested iif() conditional statements in MS-Access and because character length became too long, I wanted to use an alias in the statement.

I tried this (by accident) and it works and I'm not sure why and if I should actually use it. Below are shortened examples of the original format compared to the second with enough of the statement to get the gist of it (using generic table names).

I want to update the upDateMe table.

Original pre-alias :

```
UPDATE upDateMe 
INNER JOIN linkMe 
  ON (linkMe.UniqueID = upDateMe.UniqueID) 
 AND (linkMe.SrcNumber = upDateMe.SrcNumber) 
SET upDateMe.ExpiryDate = [linkMe].[ExpiryDate]
  , upDateMe.PermitEnd = [linkMe].[PermitEnd]...
```

Here I've reversed the tables and put in the alias 'bData':

```
UPDATE linkMe 
INNER JOIN upDateMe AS bData 
 ON (linkMe.UniqueID = bData.UniqueID) 
AND (linkMe.SrcNumber = bData.SrcNumber) 
SET bData.ExpiryDate = [linkMe].[ExpiryDate]
  , bData.PermitEnd = [linkMe].[PermitEnd]...
```

This second query works!??. I'm not really sure as to why it would. Can someone explain it??

Comment: Why use an alias the second time?

Comment: @kbballIn MS-Access, I'm using query by example with long table names (typing not a problem). Because of a lengthy set of iif() conditionals (not shown in my question). I shortened the table name so the query could accept the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Because ***the left side of the `set` statement is ALWAYS what gets updated.***

In code (most maybe not all) you set a variable by setting it = to some value on the right side. The LEFT side is always the target.

In this case, you're telling the database to update the join of linkMe and upDateMe (as bData) setting the bData values to the linkme values. You would likely get an error if you tried to update both bdate and linkMe at the same time as engines generally are only able to update 1 table at a time, since no such conflict seems to exist here, bData is updated without issue.

Comment: Small addition: Don't think of the statement as `(UPDATE upDateMe) (INNER JOIN linkMe)` but as `UPDATE (upDateMe INNER JOIN linkMe)`. So the order of the tables in the JOIN doesn't matter, neither does the alias. @r.arends

Comment: It's basically updating though an inline view.

Comment: @Andre Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: @xQbert So, combined with Andre's reply, I can look at the linkage as a type of 'object' and as Andre mentioned, as long as I don't try updating two tables at a time, it should be good. Thank you both for your replies!

Comment: @xQbert, I mixed up your name  in my earlier comment. Thank you again for your help.